# Objective-C - dataTaskWithRequest very slow

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have two method calls both with dataTaskWithRequest calls. These methods are being called back to back. If the first method does not have an error it was call the second method. But this is very slow and sometimes can take up to 2 minutes to get data from a webservice and insert data. When I manually goto the webservice URL in my browser its very very quick. But this is just slow. Here are my methods:

```
-(void)barcodeCheck:(NSString *)barcode deviceid:(NSString *)deviceId Completetion:(void (^) (NSArray * result,NSError * error))completion{
    NSString *deviceRequestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?tagId=%@&deviceId=%@",webservice,barcode, deviceId];
    NSURL *JSONURL = [NSURL URLWithString:deviceRequestString];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:JSONURL];
    NSURLSessionDataTask * dataTask = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request
                                                                      completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                                                                          if(data == nil){
                                                                              completion(nil,error);
                                                                              return;
                                                                          }
                                                                          NSError *myError;
                                                                          NSArray *tableArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&myError]];
                                                                          completion(tableArray,myError);
                                                                      }];
    [dataTask resume];
}

-(void)insertTracking:(NSString *)tag deviceId:(NSString *)phone latitude:(double)latitudeId longitude:(double)longitudeId Completetion:(void (^) (NSArray * result,NSError * error))completion{
    NSString *deviceRequestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?tag=%@&phoneId=%@&latitude=%.10f&longitude=%.10f",webservice,tag, phone, latitudeId, longitudeId];
    NSURL *JSONURL = [NSURL URLWithString:deviceRequestString];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:JSONURL];
    NSURLSessionDataTask * dataTask = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request
                                                                      completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                                                                          if(data == nil){
                                                                              completion(nil,error);
                                                                              return;
                                                                          }
                                                                          NSError *myError;
                                                                          NSArray *tableArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&myError]];
                                                                          completion(tableArray,myError);
                                                                      }];
    [dataTask resume];
}
```

and here is how I am calling them:

```
[self barcodeCheck:barcode deviceid:[[UIDevice currentDevice] name] Completetion:^(NSArray *result, NSError *error) {

        if([result count] == 0){

            UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Message" message:@"Barcode is invalid." preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

            UIAlertAction* ok = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil];
            [alertController addAction:ok];

            [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];

            ScannerMessage.text = @"READY TO SCAN";
            ScannerMessage.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

        }else{


            [self insertTracking:barcodeHolder deviceId:[[UIDevice currentDevice] name] latitude:currentLocation.coordinate.latitude longitude:currentLocation.coordinate.longitude Completetion:^(NSArray *results, NSError *error) {

                if([results count] == 0){

                        UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Message" message:@"Could not insert data" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

                        UIAlertAction* ok = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil];
                        [alertController addAction:ok];

                        [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];

                    }else{

                        ScannerMessage.text = @"SUCCESS";
                        ScannerMessage.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

                        label.text = @"BARCODE";
                        connectedLabel.text = barcode;


                    }

            }];

        }
    }];
```

Why are these so slow? Is there anything I can do speed them up?

Comment: Unaccountable delays are usually caused by threading issues. Make sure you know what thread you are on, and especially do not touch the interface or any shared resources except on the main thread.

Comment: I don't know much about threading, can you provide me with more information so to what I should be looking at?

Comment: Okay, I think the only reliable way is to put breakpoints everywhere and keep looking to see what thread you're on.

Comment: Or maybe you could log `[NSThread mainThread]` and `[NSThread currentThread]` and look to see if they are the same object, but I'm not clear on whether that is reliable.